# How to specify address instruction Arm

Tags: arm

I have some asm instruction for ARM cortex -m4, for example

```
mov R0, #4
mov R1, #5
...
```

I want that first instruction is at address X and so on.
how i can do it?

Comment: You basically need to add a `#pragma location=...` above those lines, and define the range of addresses for that specific location in the *linker-command-file* of your project. It might be slightly different, depending on the linker in use. What IDE are you using?

Comment: i am using chibistudio that is eclipse with some addition

Comment: [`.org X`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Org.html#Org).  You must be more specific.  Do you want to align it or you **MUST** have it at a specific address?  In the 2nd case, the linker is the tool to do this.

Comment: As a note, ChibiStudio uses the GNU ARM toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

In order to place a function or variable at a specific address, it must be placed in its own section.

There are several ways to do this:

- Use `__attribute__((section("name")))`
- Use the `--split_sections` compiler option
- Use the `AREA` directive from assembly language

See [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474c/BABDJCAA.html) for more information.